# How to use dependency injected variable in the same class as the bind?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, hk2

Is it possible to use injection in the same class as where the implementation is bound? For example I have

```
this.bind(ServiceAImpl.class).to(ServiceA.class).in(Singleton.class)
```

and in the same class I need

```
final var server = ServerBuilder.forPort(1234).addService(new GrpcServerRequestHandler()).build();
//Here I want to use new GrpcServerRequestHandler(injected singleton ServiceAImpl.class object)
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: I think we need more context here.  hk2 allows for dynamically binding after you create the locator which allows a lot more flexibility about when you bind new definitions